Why are messages on Kafka with cleanup.policy=compact,delete not deleted?
In our Kafka cluster there is a topic with only a few messages that sum up to 60MB distributed over many partitions. Its cleanup.policy is set to compact,delete with retention.ms set to 1 month.
Still, there are messages on that topic from two years ago.
I understand that it could be due to the fact that all messages are on the active segment especially considering that the setting segment.bytes is set to the default of 1 GB which is not reached.
However, the setting segment.ms is also set to the default of 7 days and to my understanding that would "force the log to roll" and make sure the segment becomes inactive and old messages are deleted.
Can you explain to me why it does not happen?

Are these records created with custom timestamps? See second bullet - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_10_1_breaking I've seen Python Kafka client doesn't default timestamp to "when record was produced", but instead "epoch-time of zero"

Our timestamps are "when record was produced"
